# How to get the `$location` before `$routeProvider` redirect?

Tags: angularjs, redirect, url-routing

I'm doing a redirect in the angularjs `config` and I can see the initial location there:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
     redirectTo: function(dummy, path, search) {
         return "/default-page";
     }
 });
```

The problem is how to pass this information anywhere else.

- I can't inject a service in the config.
- I can't inject the `$rootScope` either (so I can't broadcast it).
- I can inject the `$rootScopeProvider`, but have to use its `$get`.
- I can listen to `$routeChangeSuccess` but I can't see there the original location.
- I can listen to `$routeChangeStart`, but it's no better.

What do I want it for: Unlock a feature by using a "magic" URL like

```
.../#/cheat/a/lot?answer=43
```

It's just a debugging hack, nothing security relevant.

I guess I should do it differently (a normal page calling `$location`?), but now I'm curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me stupid.

After having spend quite some time trying to figure it out and then writing the question....

Inject $rootScope and `$location` into the service and use it in

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function() {...})
```